# What language is he using?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

I found some code in google. I want to know, which is this language? I am also searching the same in google. I can't find it.

```
$(if error == '')
<html>
   <head>
      <title>...</title>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://repace_with_your_server.com/cake2/rd_cake/dynamic_details/mikrotik_browser_detect/?loginlink=$(link-login-only)&nasid=$(identity)&ssid=Struisbaai&type=mikrotik&link_status=$(link-status)&link_login_only=$(link-login-only)&link_logout=$(link-logout)">
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
$(else)
$(var)({
    'logged_in'         : '$(logged-in)',   
    'link_login_only'   : '$(link-login-only)',
    'error_orig'        : '$(error-orig)',
    'error'         : '$(error)'
})
$(endif)
```

Comment: It could be Php, but i'm not pretty sure. I would also want to know what language he is using. If you find please update me too. Thanks

Comment: What's the extension of the file?

Comment: It is basically Html with Html meta tags used with jquery. Reference: http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv

Comment: @VikrantMore That is not jQuery just because it uses $ doesn't mean its automatically jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look like some template engine rather then separated language. You could read about the available template engines [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Template_engines). They essentially exchange the text encoded information to the underlying data, in your case I don't know which particular engine it is, however it may be something made especially for this task so it is really hard to answer your question.